# Show that $E(|X-Y|^{3/2})\leq 2 E(|X|^{3/2})$ when $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d.

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expectation, lp-spaces, independence

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. random variables such that $E(|X|^{3/2})$ is finite. Prove that $$E(|X-Y|^{3/2})\leq 2 E(|X|^{3/2})$$

This is from a past qualifying exam. I'm really stumped by the question. I tried several things with Jensen, conditional expectations, ..., to no avail.

Comment: An application of Minkowski's inequality gives this same expression but with constant $2^{3/2}$. Are you sure that the problem asks you prove it with constant 2?

Comment: @sincostan yes, I'm sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists a constant $c>0$ such that

$$|\xi|^{3/2} = c \int_{\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}} (1-\cos(u \xi)) \frac{1}{|u|^{5/2}} \, du \tag{1}$$

for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. (To prove this identity, start with the integral on the right-hand side and perform a change of variables, $z := u \xi$.) Thus,

$$\begin{align*} |X-Y|^{3/2} &= c \int_{u \neq 0} \big(1-\cos(u(X-Y) \big) \frac{1}{|u|^{5/2}} \, du \\ &= c \int_{u \neq 0} \big(1-\cos(uX) \cos(uY)-\sin(uX) \sin(uY) \big) \frac{1}{|u|^{5/2}} \, du. \end{align*}$$

Taking expectation and using the fact that the random variables are independent and identically distributed, we get

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(|X-Y|^{3/2}) &= c \int_{u \neq 0} (1-\big(\mathbb{E}\cos(uX))^2-(\mathbb{E}\sin(uX))^2 \big) \frac{1}{|u|^{5/2}} \, du. \end{align*}$$

As

$$\big[ \mathbb{E}(1-\cos(uX))\big]^2+ \big[ \mathbb{E}\sin(uX)\big]^2 \geq 0$$

we have

$$-(\mathbb{E}\cos(uX))^2-(\mathbb{E}\sin(uX))^2 \leq 1-2 \mathbb{E}\cos(uX),$$

and so

$$\mathbb{E}(|X-Y|^{3/2}) \leq 2c \mathbb{E} \int_{u \neq 0} (1-\cos(uX)) \frac{1}{|u|^{5/2}} \, du \stackrel{(1)}{=} 2\mathbb{E}(|X|^{3/2}).$$

Comment: Quite nice. That the inequality in the middle of the proof suffices, is still rather mysterious to me in the sense that I cannot connect it to other known facts (by contrast with, say, the representation (1), if you see what I mean). Are there other situations where this is also the key?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this approach also proves that $$E(|X-Y|^a)\leqslant2E(|X|^a)$$ for every $$0<a<2$$ which is interesting for $$1<a<2$$

Comment: @Did yes, since there is an analogous integral representation for $|\xi|^{\alpha}$, $\alpha \in (0,2)$, the proof generalizes easily to this setting. In fact, the proof shows $$\mathbb{E}(\psi(X-Y)) \leq 2 \mathbb{E}(\psi(X))$$ for any continuous negative definite real-valued function $\psi$. Regarding your other question about the inequality in the middle of the proof: I have no idea; I simply came up with it by writing down the inequality which I needed.

Comment: @saz Thanks for your answer. Does $(1)$ have a name ? Why did you think it would help you solve the problem ? Where can I read more about this identity ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon The mapping $\xi \mapsto |\xi|^{3/2}$ is a so-called continuous negative definite function and $(1)$ is the Lévy-Khintchine representation for it. More generally, if $\nu$ is a measure such that $\int_{u \neq 0} \min\{|u|^2,1\} \, \nu(du)<\infty$, then $$\psi(\xi) = \int_{u \neq 0} (1-\cos(u \xi)) \, \nu(du) \tag{2}$$ is a continuous negative definite function. This class of functions play an important role in the theory of Lévy processes, and this is exactly the reason why I have encountered (1) for lots of times. As mentioned in my previous comment, the proof generalizes......

Comment: to the setting of continuous negative definite functions; e.g. if $\psi$ is of the form $(2)$, then $$\mathbb{E}\psi(X-Y) \leq 2 \mathbb{E}\psi(X).$$ Why I thought that it might be useful? Well, whenever I encounter $|\xi|^{\alpha}$ (here with $\alpha=3/2$) I think of this formula... once you 
 have written it down, you see that it is quite nice because it allows you to use the independence of the random variables.